# Javascript not executed - suspecting Loadpage and ID issues but I'm stuck

Tags: javascript

I'm not a developper but I have some notions...
I'm developping a website with a basic index.html page that has a header with buttons and a "content" section where it 'loads' the different page.
This works well.

However, as soon as I have a script in the HTML page I load, there are never executed.

Here is the index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The injHallas</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
    <style>
       
<!-- deleted because not the problem -->

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('home.html')">HOME</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('whitepaper.html')">WHITEPAPER</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('buy_nft.html')">BUY INJHALLAS</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('buy_oil.html')">BUY $OIL</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('marketplace.html')">MARKETPLACE</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('airdrop.html')">AIRDROP</button>
        <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('marketplace.html')">RAFFLES</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent('partners.html')">PARTNERS</button>
            <button class="button">CONTACT US</button>
        </div>
        <div class="image-wrapper-discord">
            <a href="https://discord.gg/vEUKtzjuNP" target="_blank"><img src="/media/images/discord.png" alt="Discord Icon"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-wrapper-x">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/theinjhallas" target="_blank"><img src="/media/images/x.png" alt="Twitter Icon"></a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="custom-font">The injHallas</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Content will be loaded dynamically here -->
    </div>

    <script>
        function loadContent(page) {
            fetch(page)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error loading page: ', error));
        }

        // Load home page by default when the page loads
        loadContent('countdown.html');

        function showHomePage() {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I open the website, it loads countdown.html...

Here is the code of countdown.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Countdown Timer</title>
<style>
    body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #2e3134;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            color: #EFDAB4; /* Set text color */
            text-align: center;
    }

    .countdown {
        font-size: 100px; /* Adjust font size */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh; /* Adjust height as needed */
        font-family: 'Adrip1', sans-serif; /* Specify custom font */
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Adrip1';
      src: url('fonts/Adrip1.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Path to the font file */
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="countdown" id="countdown"></div>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("March 25, 2024 15:00:00 UTC").getTime();

// Update the countdown every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get the current date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Calculate the remaining time
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Calculate days, hours, minutes, and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the countdown
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours "
    + minutes + "min " + seconds + "sec ";

    // If the countdown is over, display a message
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED!!!";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here, the script to display the countdown is never executed...

I suspect an issue like Parent/Child with ID or something like that but I'm stuck...

in the browser debugger, I tried to look at the "complete HTML"... meaning the index.html with the countdown.html but still I don't understand why the script is not executed...

**
"fun fact" : when I load my website pointing directly to countdown.html ([www.mysite.com/countdown.html](http://www.mysite.com/countdown.html)), the script WORKS !!!!**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><script src="chrome-extension://jnlgamecbpmbajjfhmmmlhejkemejdma/static/js/inpage.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://dlcobpjiigpikoobohmabehhmhfoodbb/inpage.js" id="argent-x-extension" data-extension-id="dlcobpjiigpikoobohmabehhmhfoodbb"></script><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The injHallas</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://theinjhallas.com/media/images/favicon.png">
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Arabian';
            src: url('/fonts/Arabian.ttf') format('truetype');
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        header {
            background-color: #2e3134;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #EFDAB4;
            position: relative;
            border-bottom: 0px solid goldenrod;
        }
        #content {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .button {
            background-color: goldenrod;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px 0;
            margin-right: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 125px;
            font-weight: bold;
            transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
        }
        .button:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px goldenrod;
        }
        .button:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        .custom-font {
            font-family: 'Arabian', sans-serif;
            font-size: 64px;
        }
        .image-wrapper-discord {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            right: 20px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
        .image-wrapper-discord img {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
        .image-wrapper-x {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            right: 70px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
        .image-wrapper-x img {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }      
      
      
        @keyframes glow {
            0% {
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 goldenrod;
            }
            50% {
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px goldenrod;
            }
            100% {
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 goldenrod;
            }
        }
        header {
            animation: glow 2s infinite alternate;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;home.html&#39;)">HOME</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;whitepaper.html&#39;)">WHITEPAPER</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;buy_nft.html&#39;)">BUY INJHALLAS</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;buy_oil.html&#39;)">BUY $OIL</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;marketplace.html&#39;)">MARKETPLACE</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;airdrop.html&#39;)">AIRDROP</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;marketplace.html&#39;)">RAFFLES</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="loadContent(&#39;partners.html&#39;)">PARTNERS</button>
            <button class="button">CONTACT US</button>
        </div>
        <div class="image-wrapper-discord">
            <a href="https://discord.gg/vEUKtzjuNP" target="_blank"><img src="./The injHallas_files/discord.png" alt="Discord Icon"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-wrapper-x">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/theinjhallas" target="_blank"><img src="./The injHallas_files/x.png" alt="Twitter Icon"></a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="custom-font">The injHallas</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="content">



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Countdown Timer</title>
<style>
    body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #2e3134;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            color: #EFDAB4; /* Set text color */
            text-align: center;
    }

    .countdown {
        font-size: 100px; /* Adjust font size */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh; /* Adjust height as needed */
        font-family: 'Adrip1', sans-serif; /* Specify custom font */
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Adrip1';
      src: url('fonts/Adrip1.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Path to the font file */
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
</style>


<div class="countdown" id="countdown"></div>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("March 25, 2024 15:00:00 UTC").getTime();

// Update the countdown every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get the current date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Calculate the remaining time
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Calculate days, hours, minutes, and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the countdown
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours "
    + minutes + "min " + seconds + "sec ";

    // If the countdown is over, display a message
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "$OIL IS LIVE ON DOJOSWAP !!!";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</div>

    <script>
        function loadContent(page) {
            fetch(page)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error loading page: ', error));
        }

        // Load home page by default when the page loads
        loadContent('countdown.html');

        function showHomePage() {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
        }

    </script>


</body></html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A script inserted with `innerHTML` does not get executed, that is a safety browsers built in. You are better of making one script for your site and executing the correct functions when loading certain content. This is mainly to prevent accidentally executing scripts you'd rather not when fetching data from external resources.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the "Console"-tab in the debugger-window?

Comment: A good way to solve this is to load all the JS in an external js file and have the event handlers there too. You will then delegate the event handling to the nearest static container that is available to all pages - in your case "content". Ditto with the menu. Instead of having inline onclick, use eventListener on the navigation div and data-attributes on the buttons